# AWS Serverless How do I add and call a private API gateway to my web application so I can securely process sensitive data

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, api-gateway

I am trying to understand the best approach for working with highly sensitive data within my web application. My problem is this:
I have to gather information from the client. I then use that information to make a request to a third party API, which then returns information about the client (for example, personal financial data). I need to store this information in a DynamoDB and present the information back to the client in the front end. What is the recommended architecture to securely handle the data?

My initial thought was to create a custom VPC and private API gateway with a private API integration (to interact with the 3rd party API). What is the proven way to call the private API from my application? Do I need to call a function that is in a public subnet within the VPC and which then calls the private subnet? What is the proven way to write the data to dynamoDB once the 3rd party responds?

**UPDATE**

So I was looking around and saw approach that seemed to make sense to me. Within my public API I can attach my lambda to my VPC, Subnets, and Security Groups. Attaching in this way doesn't deploy the lambda inside the VPC, but an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) is created to link the lambda function and the different subnets inside the VPC. So I can use my lambda as a forwarder and send the message along to the private API in the VPC. Now I am getting a "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource:.." response back. The work continues.

**UPDATE**

I think my assumption *"Attaching in this way doesn't deploy the lambda inside the VPC, but an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) is created to link the lambda function and the different subnets inside the VPC."*... is wrong and in fact the lambda will run in my custom VPC. Would like to confirm, because then if that is correct and it is running in my custom VPC, then I am all set.

Comment: Using private API which you expose to the internet through some proxy is rather counter productive. Do you really need to have private api?

Comment: So I need to secure one of my lambda's in a custom VPC for enhanced security and I can't get around that. I need to front the lambda with something, and figured a private API gateway would be best; however, I am open to other considerations. What I keep seeing pop up is to create a VPC link and connect to an NLB. Haven't tried that yet but it is what I keep seeing recommended.